# Activex checkbox variable name in Excel Worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

To begin with, I have two worksheets named "Speed" and "Status" and 5 activex checkboxes placed in sheet "Status". The initial condition is that cell colors are **white** and all checkboxes are set to True. Basing on information from "Speed", I want the checkboxes to be automatically rechecked or not. If unchecked, some cell color will be changed to **black** in sheet "Status".

In other words: If cell value in "Speed" is less than 60 or different from letter C or different from letter I, specific cell in "Status" will continue to be white (checkbox is not altered and is checked). If the user manually uncheck, the cell will change to black.

The code snipped is not working as it should. There is no loop. ***[Correction is included !]***

```
Sub ButtonTEST()

Dim x, a As Integer
Dim obj As Object
Dim var As String

a = 1
x = 2

var = "CheckBox" & a  '<----- Correction: this line should go to [1]

Set obj = Sheets("Status").OLEObjects(var) '<----- Correction: this line should go to [2]

 For a = 1 To 5

     ' [1] insert here first
     ' [2] insert here in this order

        If (Sheets("Speed").Range("A" & x).Value >= 60) Or _
           (Sheets("Speed").Range("B" & x).Value = "I") Or _
           (Sheets("Speed").Range("C" & x).Value = "C") Then

            obj.Object.Value = False

        Else

           obj.Object.Value = True

        End If

        a = a + 1     '<----Correction : this line should be deleted
        x = x + 1
 Next a

End Sub
```

**The code below is placed within sheet "Status", where all the activex checkboxes are**

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()

With Sheets("Status")
            .Activate

    If ActiveSheet.CheckBox1.Value = True Then

        .Range("B10").Select
            With Selection.Interior
                .Pattern = xlNone
                .TintAndShade = 0
                .PatternTintAndShade = 0
            End With

   Else

            .Range("B10").Select
            With Selection.Interior
                .Pattern = xlSolid
                .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
                .TintAndShade = 0
                .PatternTintAndShade = 0
            End With

    End If
End With

End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox2_Click()

With Sheets("Status")
          .Activate

    If ActiveSheet.CheckBox2.Value = True Then

            .Range("B11").Select
            With Selection.Interior
                .Pattern = xlNone
                .TintAndShade = 0
                .PatternTintAndShade = 0
            End With

    Else

            .Range("B11").Select
            With Selection.Interior
                .Pattern = xlSolid
                .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
                .TintAndShade = 0
                .PatternTintAndShade = 0
            End With
    End If
 End With

End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox3_Click()

With Sheets("Status")
         .Activate

    If ActiveSheet.CheckBox3.Value = True Then

            .Range("B12").Select
            With Selection.Interior
                .Pattern = xlNone
                .TintAndShade = 0
                .PatternTintAndShade = 0
            End With

    Else

            .Range("B12").Select
            With Selection.Interior
                .Pattern = xlSolid
                .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
                .TintAndShade = 0
                .PatternTintAndShade = 0
            End With

    End If
 End With

End Sub
Private Sub CheckBox4_Click()

 With Sheets("Status")
            .Activate

    If ActiveSheet.CheckBox4.Value = True Then


            .Range("B13").Select
            With Selection.Interior
                .Pattern = xlNone
                .TintAndShade = 0
                .PatternTintAndShade = 0
            End With
    Else
            .Range("B13").Select
            With Selection.Interior
                .Pattern = xlSolid
                .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
                .TintAndShade = 0
                .PatternTintAndShade = 0
            End With
    End If
End With

End Sub
Private Sub CheckBox5_Click()

With Sheets("Status")
            .Activate

    If ActiveSheet.CheckBox5.Value = True Then

            .Range("B14").Select
            With Selection.Interior
                .Pattern = xlNone
                .TintAndShade = 0
                .PatternTintAndShade = 0
            End With

    Else

            .Range("B14").Select
            With Selection.Interior
                .Pattern = xlSolid
                .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
                .TintAndShade = 0
                .PatternTintAndShade = 0
            End With

    End If
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: 1) your checkbox is set outside the loop so never changes; 2) you don't need to increment a inside your loop as it does so automatically - yours will go 1-3-5.

Comment: @SJR Thank you for your explanations. Implemented the correction needed by following your tips in the above code. Problem is solved! Best regards.